# Формирование файла в формате XML

Tags: delphi

Помогите пожалуйста, как реализовать программно формирование файла в формате xml для Сбербанка (реестр зарплата на карточки). Я склоняюсь к delphi, там должны быть наверно какие-то компоненты. Помогите, пожалуйста.
Помогите может кто программно поможет. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

[Руководство по работе с XML (Lazarus/Delphi)](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/XML_Tutorial/ru).

Answer (score 0):

TXmlDocument на вкладке Internet

Answer (score 0):

Вдогонку, есть еще сторонний, но очень удобный NativeXML